# Any DatePicker component immediately errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datetimepicker, mui-x

I am using react and typescript. I did everything according to the [instructions](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/), and when I add any component to the project, I get errors. In an empty new project everything works fine. My code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { MenuItem, TextField } from "@mui/material"
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider, DemoContainer  } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import dayjs from "dayjs";

export default function WorkPanel(): JSX.Element {

    const TypeRole = [
        {
            value: 'WOLUser',
            label: 'WOLUser',
        },
        {
            value: 'ExtendedUser',
            label: 'ExtendedUser',
        },
        {
            value: 'Administrator',
            label: 'Administrator',
        }
    ];
    
    return (
        <div className="WorkPaper">
            <TextField
                id="TextField-login"
                label='Login'
                variant="outlined"
                disabled={true}
                sx={{
                    marginBottom: "10px"
                }}
            />
            <TextField
                id="TextField-FIO"
                label='FIO'
                variant="outlined"
                disabled={true}
                sx={{
                    marginBottom: "10px"
                }}
            />
            <TextField
                id="TextField-Role"
                label={'Роль'}
                select
                variant="outlined"
                defaultValue="WOLUser"
                helperText="Change role"
                sx={{
                    marginBottom: "10px"
                }}
            >
                {TypeRole.map((option) => (
                    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                        {option.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </TextField>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                <DemoContainer components={['DatePicker']}>
                    <DatePicker
                        label="Live time" />
                </DemoContainer>
            </LocalizationProvider>
    
        </div>
    
    )

}
```

When I delete everything associated with the datepicker, the error disappears.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Tried updating all libraries to latest version but nothing helps.
my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "prog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/joy": "^5.0.0-alpha.86",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.7",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "^5.13.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
    "@mui/types": "^7.2.4",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.9.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.10.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "merge": "^2.1.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-core": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-expiration": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-precaching": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-routing": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-strategies": "^6.5.4",
    "workbox-streams": "^6.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "ajv": "^8.11.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "nan": "^2.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
```

Comment: One error you keep getting is "Hooks can only be called from the inside of a functional component", while your work above is typed as JSX element. I'm unfamiliar with `AdapterDayjs` but is that a hook? It seems like either that or `useContext` is being called in something that isn't a functional component (i.e. a class component or a JSX element)